# Как вывести данные из базы данных?

Tags: php, база-данных

Никак не получается вывести текст из базы данных на страницу, сижу уже часов 6 не получается. С подключением БД все нормально.
Сам не разбираюсь. Делал по видео. Но увы, все печально.
Тема гороскопы. Просто нужна смена текста и даты, с помощью БД.
Я ввожу в бд текст и на странице должен меняться текст.
Буду благодарен за помощь)

Код подключения:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "Genel", "1120118f");
$db = mysql_select_db("Genel");

if(! $connection  || !$db) {
    exit (mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM Zodiac");

mysql_close();
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row[' title '] , "<br>";
}
```

Comment: 1. Перестанте использовать **mysql_x** (пользуйтесь **mysqli_x**, **pdo**). 2. Внимательно читайте документацию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php. 3. Вы закрываете связь с сервером до то го как читаете результаты(не передав дескриптор). 4. Вы путаете `mysql` - базу данных и `phpmyadmin` - инструмент для администрирования `mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

Названия таблиц и полей всегда окутывайте в обратные кавычки, что бы отличать поле/таблицу от оператора. Пример с выборкой поля одновременно с использованием оператора `where`

```
SELECT id, from, where WHERE id>1 // ошибка

SELECT `id`, `from`, `where` WHERE `id`>1 // вернёт результат
```

проблема вывода была в неправильной конкатенации где использовалась запятая `,` вместо точки `.` (`echo $row['title'] , "<br>";`)

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "Genel", "1120118f");

$db = mysql_select_db("Genel");

if(! $connection  || !$db) {
    exit (mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Zodiac`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['title']."<br>";
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: А пояснить что, почему и как? Судя по вопросу автор в PHP новичёк(похоже не только в PHP). От куска кода пользы не много.

Comment: @E_p отредактировал

Comment: `echo $row['title'] , "<br>"`  - абсолютно нормальный вариант. Эквивалент `echo $row['title'] ; echo "<br>";`. Но вы правы, это не конкатенация. Ну и автор сделал это не от большого знания языка. :)

Comment: Да, новичок и в html,css  и в php, дали курсовую сделать сайт связанный с гороскопами, сайт сам сделал, но нужно еще бд, нужно чтобы при вводе текста в бд, на странице менялся текст. Пытался кучу раз, но никак

Comment: и этот код не подошёл? имейте ввиду что названия полей и бд регистрозависимы. может быть `Genel` или `Zodiac` с маленькой?